# How to construct "if then else" using the array items?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays from where I want to construct dynamically a series of "if...then...else" conditions as much as the number of items in the first array. Both arrays will always have the same amount of items.

They key in my attempt is that I have hundred of thousands rows that will be checked from the `if then else` , so I want it to break when a result is found.

How can I construct this better?

```
$checker = 0; $counter = 0;
while ($checker < 3) {
if ($usersResult[pages] <= $the_score[$counter]) {
    echo 'found <br>';
    $checker = 5;
}
$counter++;
}
```

the first array

```
$unique_percentiles[]
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(5)
  [1]=>
  int(65)
  [2]=>
  int(80)
  [3]=>
  int(85)
  [4]=>
  int(90)
  [5]=>
  int(95)
}
```

and the second array

```
$the_score[]
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```

Comment: could  you please explain what could be the condition by using two arrays- i mean relation between two arrays

Comment: i don't understand you, are you just searching for an item in an array?

Comment: Where does `$unique_percentiles` come into this? I don't see it in your first snippet. And how, _exactly_, do you want your arrays to be used? (Side note: Don't mix `$camelCase` and `$snake_case`. Pick one and use it consistently.)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of foreach to iterate like

```
// i consider two arrays  $the_score and  $unique_percentiles
foreach($the_score as $key=>$val)
{ 
   // you can make condition in two arrays like,
   // $val hold the value of first array - $the_score 
   // and corresponding element of second array is accessible by $unique_percentiles[$key]
   if(your_contidion)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```